# ¿Se dice "Dios los cría y ellos se juntan" o "crea"? ¿Cuál es el origen de la expresión?

Tags: historia, refranes

Leyendo una revista este fin de semana, veía que mencionaban el refrán:

> Dios los *crea* y ellos se juntan.

Se me hizo extraño pues en el día a día, al hablar, en películas, en algún cuento o chiste había leído:

> Dios los *cría* y ellos se juntan.

Al buscar en el DLE, [criar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BFyuWxK) tiene como acepción 11:  *tr. Rel. Dicho de Dios: Dar ser a algo que antes no existía*. Y según Google Ngram, hasta la primera mitad del siglo XIX solo se había escrito unas cuantas veces con *crea*, pero de ahí en adelante es mayor el uso del vocablo *cría* en el refrán (salvo un periodo entre 1870 y 1877)

Quizá sea por mostrarse más correctos que se haya usado la primera pero en realidad, ¿cuál es la versión original? y ¿cuál es el origen de este refrán?

Comment: Yo conocía la frase como "Dios los cría y el diablo los junta".

Comment: En Cuba se usa mucho "Dios los cria, y el diablo los junta.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

En los siglos XVII y XVIII la palabra *criar* tenía como primera acepción la de "producir de la nada". Covarrubias (1611) da directamente su definición en latín:

> Creare est aliquid de nihilo producere in effectu.

Y el Diccionario de Autoridades (1729) da esta como primera definición:

> Producir algo de la nada, dar ser à lo que antes no lo tenía, lo que solo es próprio de la Omnipotencia Divina.

Luego ya vienen otras acepciones, como la de "producir" en general o la de "educar". Curiosamente, este diccionario recoge el refrán, y expresa su significado de la siguiente forma:

> Dios los *cría*, y ellos se juntan. Refr. con que se dá à entender lo poderosa que es la confrontacion de genios y naturáles, que aunque hayan los hombres nacido y criadose en partes distantes, con facilidád se unen los que son de un mismo genio y condición.

Y da la siguiente traducción al latín:

> Deus creat, quos sociat interim vita.

En el CORDE me aparece la expresión en su forma *Dios los cría* como muy pronto en 1841, y no veo ningún caso de *Dios los crea*. En todo caso, como ves el Diccionario de Autoridades lo recoge como *cría*, aunque teniendo en cuenta el significado que tenía la palabra por entonces, daba igual que fuera *cría* que *crea*. De hecho este diccionario recoge *crear* como "lo mismo que Criar". Y de ahí hacia atrás la palabra *crear* no viene recogida por ningún otro diccionario.

Answer (score 2):

Yo creo que *"Dios los cría... y ellos se juntan"* y *"Dios los crea... y ellos se juntan"* son en realidad la misma expresión, y están claramente diciendo lo mismo. Por eso, lo que importa en este refrán es la segunda parte, de la que la *Enciclopedia Micronet* ofrece una buena interpretación:

> Los malintencionados se asocian casi por instinto.

Efectivamente: este refrán no pone el acento en la primera parte (de dónde vienen dichas personas), sino en *lo que hacen*. Es decir, que es irrelevante si el verbo es "criar" o es "crear", que por cierto ha sido bien explicado en otras respuestas.
El [refranero del Centro Virtual Cervantes lo explica](https://cvc.cervantes.es/lengua/refranero/ficha.aspx?Par=58529&Lng=0) aún con más detalle, y también acentúa más las acciones y actitudes, que el origen de quienes las llevan a cabo:

> Alude con cierta ironía a la inclinación natural que lleva a juntarse a los de un mismo genio y temperamento. Se aplica más bien a personas de conducta censurable.

En cualquier caso, la forma “cría” es con diferencia mucho más usada que “crea”. De hecho, existe incluso una obra de teatro titulada precisamente así, *Dios los cría y ellos se juntan*, de Bretón de los Herreros.

Answer (score 0):

Estoy seguro que es "Dios los crea y ellos se juntan", pues no tiene sentido "Dios los cría". De hecho, en México el refrán es "Dios los hace y ellos se juntan", lo cual hace sentido. Y hoy se me ocurrió el refrán "Dios crea, pero no cría", lo cual significa que Dios te manda al mundo, pero tus padres te crían y tú mismo tienes que aprender a sobrevivir en el mundo.

Lo mismo pasa con el refrán "Nunca es tarde si la dicha es buena", lo cual para mí no tiene sentido, pues la dicha siempre es buena o no es dicha. El refrán debe ser  "Nunca es tarde si la dicha llega".

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta. Entra en contradicción con las otras respuestas, ¿podrías aportar referencias que sustenten tu hipótesis? Dale a [edit] para añadirlas, ¡gracias!